# 100 consecutive days, but no "Fanatic" badge?

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

I've hit the magic 100 consecutive days on SO, but I haven't got my "Fanatic" badge.

Hitting 100 days has been a bit of a goal for me - especially as this would be my first gold badge - so I'm feeling a little distraught. :-(

Is there some sort of delayed update or has something gone wrong?

Comment: I can imagine the immediate frustration after 100 consecutive days of loyalty... :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If it says "visited XXX days, 100 consecutive" on your profile, I'm pretty sure the badge should be on it's way pretty soon. Give it time; don't feel distraught just yet!

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 26):

It appears I just needed to wait a little while. It is a little annoying that the count in the profile is updated and there is a delay before the badge comes through.

I thought rather than delete my question that I would answer it instead so that the next person this delay affects will wait patiently and not post silly questions. :-)

Comment: Thanks for saving me the effort! I found this question on my way to asking it myself.